# Translate doctrine query from default Symfony 3 translation file

Tags: symfony, doctrine, translation

In my AdRepository i'm getting an list of list conditions of the product. These have names like 'NEW', 'GOOD'... I use the following simple query to get the list:

```
   $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('ad')
        ->select('ad.condition as name')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Now I want to translate the name field from the standard Symfony translation files, so not from the database. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: sorry but your condition is not variable?? my mean is that, your condition is static and not flexible and change by user? for example always use this names `{'Good', "Bad", "New"}`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if thats the best way to do it, but you could (I assume you're using Twig) use an if and give the translation variable depending on the condition name.

```
{% if condition.name === "GOOD" %} 
      {{ 'condition.good'|trans }} 
{% else %} 
      ... 
{% endif %}
```

Of course thats a lot of ifs, if you have many conditions.

Comment: Yes I'm using twig only the results are send via Ajax and added to the frontend by Javascript. Therefore the translation needs to be done in the backend at or just after the query.

Comment: You can get the translator in your controller `$this->get('translator');` and translate the stuff there before returning it, or you could create a translation map of all such translations and pass it down to the javascript and use it there to look up and inject the correct translations.